# How to get thread dump for WebLogic server?

Tags: weblogic

Hi

How do I get thread dump for WebLogic server?

I have cases of thread locking up happening a number of times.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do that.

- Send a `SIGQUIT`, either via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd> on Windows) or with a `kill -3 <pid>`
- Use `jstack <pid>` (or `jstack -F <pid>` if the process is hung)
- Use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/)
- Use WLST and `threadDump()`

The first option has usually my preference. If you need to script some kind of monitoring tool, WLST is extremely powerful.

Comment: how does the kill -3 works? because i have a production server and does killing it means it will stop servicing requests?

Comment: @ssdsd: No, it won't. A kill -3 sends a SIGQUIT, not a SIGKILL (kill -9) nor a SIGTERM (kill -15). It won't "kill" the process.

Comment: So if i run this command what will happen actually and where can i find the log files for it?

Comment: @ssdsd: It will generate a thread dump, as requested. The thread dump is generated in the standard output that you might have redirected to a log.

Answer (score 0):

For IBM Java VM: 
Set environment variable 'IBM_HEAPDUMP=true' and restart managed web server ..next time when generate the Thread dump (kill -3) , the heap dump will be also generated.